# PHP - OOP - Why is my function called twice?

Tags: php, oop

I'm facing a problem that my function is called twice everytime i submit my form

my form file with the call to the function:

```
<?php
require "classes/loginClass.php";
$login = new login;
$login->login();
?>

<form action="" method="POST">
    <label for="username">username: </label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required><br/>
    <label for="password2">password: </label>
    <input type="password" id="password2" name="password2" required><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="login">
</form>
```

my class and function:

```
class login {

    public function login() {
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            echo "submit";
        }
    }
}
```

So everytime when i press the submit button, "submit" get echoed twice. Which means my function is called twice. I do not quite get why.

Comment: Because when you have a function with the same name as a class, it's treated as the constructor.  This is how it worked in PHP4, before PHP5 introduced `__construct()`.  It exists for backwards compatibility.

Comment: On a side note. I would take that post global from that method if I were you. May pass the $_POST array though the constructor, and then extract and map it to the class properties. Just do anything, other than that. Its annoying me :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A method named the same as the class is considered an (old style) constructor, and is called every time the  object is created.

So it's called once when the object gets created, and another time when you explicitly call it.

Note that today, it's considered a better practice to implement `__construct()` rather than `ClassName()`, mainly to help with inheritance.

---

More reading material:

- **[PHP - Constructors and Deconstructors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)**
- **[PHP - Old Style Constructors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/oop4.constructor.php)**

Answer (score 6):

Your class name is login.  You do not have `__construct()`, and you have a function called `login()`.  So when you instantiate the class, `login()` is called first since you did not define `__construct()` , method name same as class becomes the constructor.  Then you are calling the `login()` function again. Hence its called twice.

Answer (score 5):

When you create a Class, you should specify a Constructor.

If you dont specify a Constructor, it's called by Magic Methods.

In Your Case, you create a Class Without a constructor, by with a function with the same name of the Class. Class Login -> Method Login. The PHP Acts like the Login Method is your constructor...

So when you call $login = new Login() you are calling the constructor that's the Login Method.

And when you call Login Method, $login->login(), you are calling it twice.

Are you understood?

Answer (score 4):

You call one time the function with the constructor, seconde time manually. In PHP 5.3.3, if you name function like the class, it's a constructor.

Answer (score 3):

In PHP 4 the constructor of a class had the same name as the class. When in PHP 5 destrutors were added the naming scheme `__construct()` was added, the old way was kept working for compatibility reasons, though.

In your case this means that `login()` will first be called as constructor, then from the explicit call